# Trying to configure github in Ubuntu 10.10 VirtualBox

Tags: github, ssh-keys

I've set up Rails on Ubuntu 10 under VirtualBox. I've managed to configure pretty much everything except for Github.

Everytime I try to `ssh git@github.com` I get a message telling me `permission denied (publickey)`. Below is the message I received after debugging:

```
david@david-VirtualBox:~/.ssh$ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/david/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/david/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/david/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/david/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/david/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/david/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve darokel
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
debug1: Trying private key: /home/david/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Could somebody help and tell me what I'm doing wrong. Also be aware that I'm a newbie :) to Ruby and Git/Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are instructions on Github for this. You need to locate your ssh public key (most likely in your `~/.ssh` folder) and upload it to Github.

Look under your account settings, then SSH Public Keys, then over on the right, follow the link Need Help With Public Keys and it will [take you here](http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/).